# Clarification regarding cin.get()

Tags: c++

```
...
cin.get(temp,MaxLen);
while(cin && cin.get()!= '\n')
    continue;
...
```

Where temp is a char array, MaxLen is some const.

Now, this is what I think the code means.

"Get MaxLen chars from input buffer and assign to temp"
THEN
"as long as cin has no error flags and the next char is not "\n": continue "

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
cin.get(temp,MaxLen);
```

reads at most `MaxLen - 1` characters into `temp` from the standard input stream, until a `\n` is found.

The following:

```
while(cin && cin.get()!= '\n')
    continue;
```

in prose, means that we are skipping from there to the end of the line.

This means that if the topmost `get` gets to the end of the line, the while loop is going to skip over the next line. Otherwise, if all `MaxLen - 1` characters are read without finding a `\n`, then the while loop will skip the rest of the characters on that line.

Comment: So for example, if MaxLen = 5, and I enter "Hello, my name is Sam" then cin.get(temp,Maxline) gives temp = "Hell" and the purpose of the while(...) is to skip the rest of the line until the enter key was pressed, (after the m in sam)? Sorry to be annoying, I'm trying to understand everything the best I can.

Comment: @HMPARTICLE Seems like it, yes. I'd recommend trying it out though.